# Creating an Oracle trigger to stop people enrolling twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing some problems while I was trying to create a trigger. So the question I was giving is

**The event holder has noted that several participants have enrolled in multiple events in the same exhibition which they do not wish to occur. Write a trigger to prevent this issue in future exhibition.**

What I have written is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_event_enrolment
  BEFORE INSERT ON entry
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  new_exhibiton_date DATE;
  new_part_no        NUMBER;
BEGIN
  new_carn_date := (SELECT to_char(carn_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                      FROM event
                     WHERE event_id = :new.event_id);

  IF (new_carn_date IN (SELECT TO_CHAR(carn_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY')
                          FROM entry NATURAL
                          JOIN event
                         WHERE part_no = :new.part_no)) THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001,
                            'The participant has already enrolled under the same exhibition');
  END IF;
END;
```

Assume that an exhibition can have multiple events going on, the part

```
new_carn_date := (SELECT to_char(carn_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY') 
                    FROM event 
                   WHERE event_id = :new.event_id);
```

is giving me error and I dont know how to fix it.

Thank you in advance for your help. If you need more background information I will be more than happy to provide it.

===============================================================
I have tried using one of the solutions provided below, the trigger can be compiled but there's error.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_event_enrolment BEFORE
        INSERT ON entry
        FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
        new_exhibition_date DATE;
    BEGIN
        SELECT
            exhibition_date
        INTO new_exhibition_date
        FROM
            event
        WHERE
            event_id = :new.event_id;
    
        IF  new_exhibition_date IN (
            SELECT
                exhibition_date
            FROM
                     entry
                NATURAL JOIN event
            WHERE
                part_no = :new.part_no
        )  THEN
            raise_application_error(-20001, 'The participant has already enroled under the same exhibition');
        END IF;
END;
```

But it is giving me error like

Trigger CHECK_EVENT_ENROLMENT compiled

**LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- ------------------------------------------------------------- 18/21     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of the following:     ) , with group having intersect minus start union where connect The symbol "," was substituted for "JOIN" to continue.  Errors: check compiler log**

Anyone knows what is going on?

Comment: Please, put _in the title_ the error you mention. What error?

Comment: As [MT0 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72349569/256196), a unique constraint is the right way to do it and a trigger is definitely the wrong way to do it. Your biggest problem is finding a better course/teacher; one that doesn't pose useless tutorial questions, or constrain them to answers you would never use in real life.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a trigger, use a `UNIQUE` index:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX entry__carn_dt__part__no__uidx
  ON entry (event_id, TRUNC(carn_date), part_no);
```

---

If you must use a trigger (don't) then:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_event_enrolment
  BEFORE INSERT ON entry 
  FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
  num_matches PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   num_matches
  FROM   entry
  WHERE  TRUNC(carn_date) = TRUNC(:NEW.carn_date)
  AND    event_id  = :NEW.event_id
  AND    part_no   = :NEW.part_no;
  
  IF num_matches > 0 THEN 
    raise_application_error(
      -20001,
      'The participant has already enrolled under the same exhibition'
    ) ; 
  END IF; 
END;
/
```

Comment: Dear sir, your code is giving out error like "bad bind values" which is on :NEW.event_id and :NEW.part_no, may I know what's going on?

Comment: @DarrenHongWengChen They are exactly the same bind variables used in your code, so it might be easier if you told us what was going on as we do not have a [MRE] with the definitions of the tables . However, the implication is that the `entry` table does not contain the columns `part_no` and `event_id` (but we cannot confirm that as you have not described your tables).

Comment: I have successfully solved this question, thank you. There one more going on at https://stackoverflow.com/q/72358947/19166740 , if you would like to help out again, it is more than welcome!

Answer (score -1):

The syntax you are using is incorrect. The correct syntax sold be -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER check_event_enrolment BEFORE 
INSERT ON entry 
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE
       num_matches NUMBER;
BEGIN
     
     SELECT COUNT(*)
       INTO num_matches
       FROM entry
    NATURAL JOIN event
      WHERE part_no = :new.part_no
        AND event_id = :new.event_id;

     IF (num_matches > 0) THEN 
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'The participant has already enroled under the same exhibition' ) ; 
     END IF; 
END;
```

Comment: Never use implicit conversions from strings to dates. You either want `SELECT carn_date INTO new_carn_date ...`  or you want `SELECT TRUNC(carn_date) INTO new_carn_date` if you only want the time component to be midnight; what you do not want to do is convert it to a string and then have an implicit conversion back to a date. Also, you have not declared a `new_carn_date` variable.

Comment: Dear Sir, it is giving me the error >>> Encountered the symbol "JOIN" when expecting one of the following:     ) , with group having intersect minus start union where    connect The symbol "," was substituted for "JOIN" to continue. May I know what to fix ?

Comment: @DarrenHongWengChen, Can you please try the edited code.