# Creating a trigger to automatically calculate the value of total tour time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing some issue while creating a trigger that can automatically calculate the total time it takes for a tour to finish, below is the text question

**The event holder has decided to record the shortest tour time for each event type for
all future exhibitions. Add two new attributes in the EVENTTYPE table named
eventype_record and eventtype_recordholder to store the shortest tour time for
each event type and the participant (participant number) who holds the record. You
may assume that only a single participant will hold each record and that the record
holder will only be replaced by a new single participant if their tour time is less
than the current eventtype_record. Calculate the tour time attribute added in previous task when the  tour finish time is updated (ie. the participant finished the tour)**

What I currently have is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tour_time_updater 
  AFTER UPDATE OF tour_finishtime ON entry 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    UPDATE entry 
    SET tour_time = to_char(((:new.tour_finishtime - :old.tour_starttime) * 24 * 60), '9999.99');
END;
/
```

But after I try to insert a fake participant in my entry table with no finish time with this code

```
INSERT INTO entry (
    event_id,
    entry_no, 
    tour_starttime, 
    tour_finishtime,
    part_no,
    group_id,
    tour_time 

) VALUES ( 
    9,
    6,
    to_date('09:05:43', 'HH:MI:SS'),
    NULL,
    5,
    NULL, 
    NULL
);
```

and only update its tour_finishtime later

```
UPDATE entry SET tour_finishtime = to_date('10:05:43', 'HH:MI:SS')
where part_no = 5 and event_id = 9;
```

it is giving me errors like

```
**UPDATE entry SET tour_finishtime = to_date('10:05:43', 'HH:MI:SS')
where part_no = 5 and event_id = 9
Error report -
ORA-04091: table XXXXXXXX.ENTRY is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "XXXXXXXX.TOUR_TIME_UPDATER", line 5
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'XXXXXXXX.TOUR_TIME_UPDATER'**
```

Can anyone help me with that? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Don't `update` the table (literally), but

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tour_time_updater 
  BEFORE UPDATE OF tour_finishtime ON entry 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :new.tour_time := to_char(((:new.tour_finishtime - :new.tour_starttime) * 24 * 60), '9999.99');
END;
/
```

---

Code you wrote is trying to update the same table whose modification fired the trigger; for the trigger, that table is "mutating" and that's an *invalid* condition.

You *could* "fix" it by writing a compound trigger (if your database version supports it) or using a package, but - why bother, if correct way to do it is as suggested in code above?

Comment: Dear sir/madam, it is giving error
Error report -
ORA-04084: cannot change NEW values for this trigger type
04084. 00000 -  "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"
*Cause:    New trigger variables can only be changed in before row
           insert or update triggers.
*Action:   Change the trigger type or remove the variable reference.

Comment: Right; sorry, wasn't paying attention to it. It should be a BEFORE UPDATE trigger, working with only :NEW pseudocolumns. Code is now fixed; have a look, please.

Comment: Why is it before? Shouldn't I only fire the trigger when a tour_finishtime is updated?

Comment: Because - if it is AFTER - you get (as you saw) "cannot change NEW values for this trigger type"

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `TRIGGER`, use a virtual column:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entry (
    event_id        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    entry_no        NUMBER, 
    tour_starttime  DATE, 
    tour_finishtime DATE,
    part_no         NUMBER,
    group_id        NUMBER
);
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE entry ADD tour_time INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND (0)
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((tour_finishtime - tour_starttime) DAY(0) TO SECOND(0));
```

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE entry ADD tour_time NUMBER(7,2)
  GENERATED ALWAYS AS ((tour_finishtime - tour_starttime) *24 * 60);
```

---

If you must use a trigger (don't) then:

```sql
CREATE TABLE entry (
    event_id        NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
    entry_no        NUMBER, 
    tour_starttime  DATE, 
    tour_finishtime DATE,
    part_no         NUMBER,
    group_id        NUMBER,
    tour_time       INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tour_time_updater 
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF tour_finishtime ON entry 
  FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  :NEW.tour_time := (:new.tour_finishtime - :new.tour_starttime) DAY(0) TO SECOND(0);
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=f48d8ede0e2ffec5f47b304bcd121606)*